# Problems with QStatusBar->showMessage()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm writing a Qt GUI Application, but there's a strange error i can't figure out;
Here's the whole code:
main.cpp

```
#include "LevelEditor.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LevelEditor editor(argc, argv);
    editor.go();
    return 0;
}
```

LevelEditor.h

```
#ifndef LEVELEDITOR_H
#define LEVELEDITOR_H

#include <QtGui>

class LevelEditor
{
    public:
        LevelEditor(int argc, char* argv[]);
        ~LevelEditor();
        void go();
    protected:
        QApplication* app;
        QMainWindow* main_window;
        QMenuBar* menu_bar;
        QStatusBar* status_bar;
        QWidget* central;
        QMenu* menu_entry[3];
        QFrame* about_frame;

        QList<QAction*> file_actions;
        QList<QAction*> edit_actions;
        QList<QAction*> help_actions;
    private:
};

#endif // LEVELEDITOR_H
```

LevelEditor.cpp

```
#include "LevelEditor.h"
#include <QStatusBar>
LevelEditor::LevelEditor(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //initialise main objects
    app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    main_window = new QMainWindow();
    menu_bar = main_window->menuBar();
    status_bar = main_window->statusBar();
    central = main_window->centralWidget();
    about_frame = new QFrame();

    //initialise menu entries and actions
    menu_entry[0] = new QMenu();    //file
    menu_entry[1] = new QMenu();    //edit
    menu_entry[2] = new QMenu();    //about

    //creating and connecting events to action
    menu_entry[0]->setTitle("File");
    file_actions.append(new QAction("New", menu_entry[0]));
    file_actions.append(new QAction("Open", menu_entry[0]));
    file_actions.append(new QAction("Save", menu_entry[0]));
    file_actions.append(new QAction("Quit", menu_entry[0]));
    QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(triggered()), app, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(hovered()), status_bar, SLOT(showMessage("Quit this App"));
    menu_entry[0]->addActions(file_actions);
    menu_bar->addMenu(menu_entry[0]);

    //edit menu
    menu_entry[1]->setTitle("Edit");
    edit_actions.append(new QAction("Cut", menu_entry[1]));
    edit_actions.append(new QAction("Copy", menu_entry[1]));
    edit_actions.append(new QAction("Paste", menu_entry[1]));
    menu_entry[1]->addActions(edit_actions);
    menu_bar->addMenu(menu_entry[1]);

    //help menu
    help_actions.append(new QAction("About", menu_entry[2]));
    QObject::connect(help_actions.back(), SIGNAL(triggered()), about_frame, SLOT(show()));
    menu_entry[2]->setTitle("Help");
    menu_entry[2]->addActions(help_actions);
    menu_bar->addMenu(menu_entry[2]);

    about_frame->resize(400,300);
}

LevelEditor::~LevelEditor()
{
    //dtor
}

void LevelEditor::go()
{
    //nothing
    main_window->showMaximized();
    menu_bar->show();
    status_bar->show();
    app->exec();
}
```

This code compiles fine without errors.
Anyway, the debug console gives me a warning
*QObject::connect : NO such slot &QStatusBar::showMessage("Quit this App")*

The problem seems related to this line:

`QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(hovered()), status_bar, SLOT(showMessage("Quit this App"));`

I've searched in "QStatusBar.h" for the showMessage function and it is declared, but can't be called neither with "." nor "->" (even if it's public). Also tried this:
`QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(hovered()), status_bar, SLOT(showMessage("Quit this App", 0));`

and this:
`QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(hovered()), status_bar, SLOT(QStatusBar::showMessage("Quit this App"));`

But to no avail, it just won't recognise the function.

Am i missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Solved, i was taking the hard way to show a status text instead of using QAction::setStatusTip, my bad.

Comment: My Qt is somewhat rusted but if I recall correctly you need to pass a signature to connect not a function call, like: showMessage(QString) instad of showMessage("My String"). You probably need to have a slot on your own class and there call showMessage with the value you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect a signal to a slot with different signature. And you are not even using the proper connect syntax. The SLOT part should be:

```
SLOT(showMessage(const QString &))
```

It's to tell the meta object system what **type(s)** of parameters to send to the slot, not what concrete data to send.

In your case, you can't connect a signal with no parameter to a slot that expects one. You can achieve that by connecting the signal to your own slot and then call QStatusBar::showMessage from there.

Comment: This means i can't directly use a QstatusBar object and instead i have to inherit a custom class from it with my own slot, right?

Comment: You could instead create a slot in `LevelEditor` (e.g. `showQuitMessage`) which calls `status_bar->showMessage("Quit this app")`, then connect the `hovered()` signal to that slot.

Comment: @StephenChu: according to the docs your first statement is wrong. According to the docs the old mechanism of connecting signals and slots (essentially via stringified names) seems to allow for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use QSignalMapper to do what you want:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(file_actions.back(), SIGNAL(hovered()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(file_actions.back(), "Quit this app");
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)), statusBar, SLOT(showMessage(const QString &));
```

Using QSignalMapper allows you, to simply add another "hovered" messages without creating new slots for each. Simply for all other cases just use:

```
mapper->setMapping(yourAction/Button/Whater, "Your status message");
QObject::connect(yourAction/Button/Whater, SIGNAL(hovered/Other signal()), mapper, SLOT(map()))
```